# Copy from an rxvt terminal

Tags: console, cygwin, rxvt

It does copy what I want but the problem is it somehow sends a ctrl-c to my terminal which will result in the execution of the current line of command every time! This truly bugs me. Can anyone help me with that? Thanks! I am using Windows 7 btw.

The command I use to open the rxvt terminal is `C:\cygwin\bin\rxvt.exe -fn '*-courier-*-r-*-16-*' -sl  9999 -bg Black -fg Green -e /bin/bash -login`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check: what you're doing is selecting some text then hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

If that's the case, what you're seeing is two separate behaviours: most terminal emulators will do the copy as soon as you've selected the text. No need for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Just swap to another window after you've selected the text, and try and paste it.

Comment: @Bobo: In that case, you need to be a lot more clear in your question about what you're actually doing. Give us step-by-step instructions to replicate this behaviour, starting with how you open your terminal.

Comment: C:\cygwin\bin\rxvt.exe -fn '*-courier-*-r-*-16-*' -sl  9999 -bg Black -fg Green -e /bin/bash -login

Comment: @Bobo: *starting* with how you open your terminal. Step-by-step, explaining what you see happening, and what you expect to see happening where that's different.